# Data persisting with RSpec-rails in a before(:each)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have transactions set up in my *rails_helper*...

`config.use_transactional_fixtures = true`

My before each blocks look like this:

```
before(:each) do
  allow(subject).to receive_messages(
    :authenticate => true,
    :authorize => true
  )

@user_song = FactoryGirl.create(:user_song)
FactoryGirl.create(:user_playlist, user_id: @user_song.user_id, 
  album_id: @user_song.song.album_id)

allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive_messages(
  :current_user => @user_song.user
)
```

Tests fail with validation errors, but, if I insert a `Model.destroy_all` for each used model before FactoryGirl's creation, it works.  I'm confused.

Why? The [Rspec rails guide](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions) says that it should be rolled-back?  Is it something with FactoryGirl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

is for Rails builtin fixeture cleanup. It wound work with `factory_girl`. You should disable that and, install a db cleaner gem like this one: https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner

Answer (score 2):

Try to configure the database cleaner.

Add this to your Gemfile

```
gem 'database_cleaner'
```

then update your
`spec/rails_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install and setup [database cleaner gem](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner/blob/master/README.markdown). Configured and installed properly, it will fix this problem you're having. There are many blog articles to help with the setup and install if the github read me docs seem confusing. Such as [this](http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/) article